# Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type, Column cannot be null, converter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, converters

i'm trying to add a register in database using hibernate (OneToMany, ManyToOne) + spring mvc, i'm using a converter to convert String to object....this is my code:

**Model**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="sl_players")
public class Player implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id_player")
private int id;

@Column(name="name_player")
private String name

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id_team")
private Team team;
--------------------------------------------------------
@Entity
@Table(name="sl_teams")
public class Team implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id_team")
private int id;

@Column(name="name_team")
private String name;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="id_team")
private List<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
@Controller
public class PlayerController {

@Autowired
private PlayerService playerService;
@Autowired
private TeamService teamService;

@RequestMapping(value="/admin/players/save", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String addPlayer(@RequestParam("teamId") Integer teamId, @ModelAttribute("player") Player player, BindingResult result){
    System.out.print("Result: "+result.getAllErrors());
    if(0 == player.getId())
        this.playerService.save(player);
    else
        this.playerService.update(player,teamId);
    return "redirect:/admin/players";
}
@ModelAttribute("teamOptions")
public List<Team> getTeam(){
    return new LinkedList<Team>(teamService.loadAll());
}
```

**Converter**

```
@Component
public class StringToTeam implements Converter<String, Team>{

@Autowired
TeamService teamService;

@Override
public Team convert(String source) {
    System.out.print("*** inside Converter ***");
    return teamService.get(Integer.parseInt(source));
}
```

**servlet-context**

```
<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService"/>
<beans:bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="converters">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:bean id="roleToUserProfile" class="com.project.converter.StringToTeam"/>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

this is the output:

```
Result: [Field error in object 'player' on field 'team': rejected value [2]; codes [typeMismatch.player.team,typeMismatch.team,typeMismatch.com.project.model.Team,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [player.team,team]; arguments []; default message [team]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.project.model.Team' for property 'team'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.project.soccerleagueapp.model.Team] for property 'team': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]]
ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Column 'id_team' cannot be null
```

Anyone can help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this example :

**Myconverter**

```
@Component("applicationToFluxConverter")
public class ApplicationToFluxConverter implements Converter<String, PIL_P_APPLCTN> {

    static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApplicationToFluxConverter.class);

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("pIL_P_APPLCTN_SERVICE")
    IService<PIL_P_APPLCTN> appService;

    /**
     * 
     * 
     * @see org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter#convert(java.lang.Object)
     */
    public PIL_P_APPLCTN convert(String element) {
        Integer id = Integer.parseInt((String) element);
        PIL_P_APPLCTN app = appService.findById(id);
        logger.info("Application : {}", app);
        return app;
    }
}
```

**AppConfig:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.fussa.fyby")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    ApplicationToFluxConverter applicationToFluxConverter;

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverter(applicationToFluxConverter);
    }
//....
    }
```